# Beginner Childnodes are being returned as undefined after a clone, so I am unable to set their attributes

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am not sure why I cannot change the attributes of my childnodes.  They appear to be coming back as undefined.  Im not sure if its because they are in  a list or not.  After some testing I have found that when I put the nodes in a list things start to hit the fan, I can nologer set any attributes after that

```
<div id="add_contact" >

    <li id="li_3" >



    <label class="description" for="element_3"><h2>Contact</h2> </label>
    <span>
        <input id="element_3_1" name= "acct_first" onchange="javascript:contacts();" value=" " class="element text" maxlength="255" size="20" value=""/>
        <label>First</label>
    </span>
    <span>
        <input id="element_3_2" name= "acct_last" onchange="javascript:contacts();" class="element text" maxlength="255" size="20" value=""/>
        <label>Last</label>
    </span> 
    </li>       

    <li id="li_27" >
    <label class="description" for="element_27">Email Address </label>
    <div>
        <input id="element_27" name="acct_cont" onchange="javascript:contacts();" class="element text large" type="text" maxlength="200" value=""/> 
        <!--<label for="element_15">Seperate Multiple Emails With A Space</label>-->
    </div>
    <!--<p class="guidelines" id="guide_15"><small>Quality Control Contact</small></p> 
    p class="guidelines" id="guide_15"><small>Seperate Multiple Emails With A Space</small></p>-->
    </li>


    <li id="li_4" >
    <label class="description" for="element_4">Phone </label>
    <span>
        <input id="element_4_1" name="acct_phone" onchange="javascript:contacts();" class="element text" size="20" maxlength="20" value="" type="text"> 
        <label for="element_4_1">Please Include Country Code If Outside The United States</label>

        <p class="guidelines" id="guide_4_1"><small>Please Include Country Code If Outside The United States</small></p>
    </span>

    </li>       



    <li id="li_13" >
    <label class="description" for="element_13">Fax </label>
    <span>
        <input id="element_13_1" name="acct_fax" onchange="javascript:contacts();" class="element text" size="20" maxlength="20" value="" type="text"> 
        <label for="element_13_1"></label>
    </span>


    </li>   

            <li id="li_6" >
    <label class="description" for="element_6">Type Of Contact (Select all that apply) </label>

    <div>


        <span>
        <input type="checkbox" name="contact" value="">Purchasing<br>
        <!--<p class="guidelines" id="guide_6_1"><small>For Questions</small></p>-->
        </span>
        <span>
        <input type="checkbox" name="contact" value="">Quality Control<br>

        </span>
        <span>
        <input type="checkbox" name="contact" value="">Accounts Payable<br>

        </span>
        </br>



        <!--<label for="element_6">Seperate Multiple Emails With A Space</label>-->
    </div>

    <!--<p class="guidelines" id="guide_6"><small>Seperate Multiple Emails With A Space</small></p> -->

    </li>   



</div>
```

MY Script:

```
var counter = 1;

function moreFields() {
    counter++;
    var newFields = document.getElementById('add_contact').cloneNode(true);
    newFields.id = '';
    newFields.style.display = 'block';
    var newField = newFields.childNodes;
    for (var index = 0; index < newField.length; index++) {
        document.write(newField[i]);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < newField.length; i++) {
        var theName = newField[i].name
        if (theName) newField[i].name = theName + counter;
    }
    var insertHere = document.getElementById('add_contact');
    insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newFields, insertHere);
}
```

I have Created a template without a list and everything works fine but in order to style it with the rest of the form I need it in a list:

```
<div id="add_contact" style="display:none" >

<label class="description" for="element_3"><h2>Contact</h2> </label>    
<input id="element_3_1" name= "acct_first" onchange="contacts();" value=" " class="element text" maxlength="255" size="20" value=""/>
<input id="element_3_2" name= "acct_last" onchange="contacts();" class="element text" maxlength="255" size="20" value=""/>  


<input id="element_27" name="acct_cont" onchange="contacts();" class="element text large" type="text" maxlength="200" value=""/> 
<input id="element_4_1" name="acct_phone" onchange="contacts();" class="element text" size="20" maxlength="20" value="" type="text"> 
<input id="element_13_1" name="acct_fax" onchange="contacts();" class="element text" size="20" maxlength="20" value="" type="text"> 



<input type="checkbox" name="contact" value="">Quality Control


<input type="checkbox" name="contact" value="">Accounts Payable

<input type="checkbox" name="contact" value="">Purchasing


</div>
```

Using This:

```
    <script>

var counter = 1;

function moreFields() {
    counter++;
    var newFields = document.getElementById('add_contact').cloneNode(true);

    newFields.id = '';
    for (var index = 0; index < newFields.length; index++) {
        console.log(newField[i]);
    }

newFields.style.display = 'block';


    var newField = newFields.childNodes;



    for (var i=0; i<newField.length;i++) {
        var theName = newField[i].name

            newField[i].name = theName + counter;   
            newField[i].value=newField[i].name;
            newField[i].id=newField[i].name;




    }
    var insertHere = document.getElementById('add_contact');
    insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newFields,insertHere);

}


</script>
```

Comment: It's probably because you are using `document.write`. Use `console.log` instead. Have a look at the [documentation of `document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write). When you use it, you are removing every existing element. [Learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) and you should see some error like `TypeError: Cannot read property parentNode of null`. Also, `insertBefore` expects a single node, not a list of nodes.

Comment: And immediately remove those `javascript:` labels! They're superfluous, if not wrong.

Comment: I have it working correctly now if I remove the list but once everything is back in the list things stop working.  It seems that once the list is in place it is only picking up three childnodes

Comment: I am a little confused as to what is being considered a childnode, When I look at the debugger I am seeing that It is considering a <BR> tag as a node and trying to assign it a ID, but when a list comes I am unsure when it only picks up 3 childnodes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var newInputs = newFields.getElementsByTagName('input');

Allowed me to get to the proper nodes